# Steam servers - Error code 2 - Fat32 error(Portal 2 steam via wine)

Tags: wine, steam

I have a dual boot computer, 64 bit Windows 7 and 64 bit Ubuntu 13.04. I have Steam installed on my computer on the Windows 7 side, however I also use it from the Ubuntu side via Wine as well. When I was trying to start Portal 2 on the Ubuntu side however, a "completing installation" window came up. After the game's loading got to one percent it returned this error:

`The Steam servers are too busy to handle you request for Portal 2. Error code (2)`

So I went to the Steam Powered site and looked up the error code and it said the fallowing:

> Many of these issues were tied to FAT32 drives which has been
>   corrected in a Steam update. Some users have also reported moving the
>   Steam installation to the default C:\ Drive will correct this issue.
>   If the issue persists, please contact Steam Support.

So I updated Steam and it still gives me this error. I would contact Steam support but it's natively for windows and mac only and I'm using Ubuntu so they cant help me. Any suggestions?

EDIT: To clarify, I can NOT just install the Linux version of Steam, as the game I want to play is not compatible with Linux. Thus, it won't let me download it or install it.

Comment: Why do you use Wine as Steam is available for Ubuntu? Just search for it in the Software Centre.

Comment: because the game I want to play is not available for Linux thus it wont let me install it

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that only Portal 1 is currently available for Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the 25th of February, 2014, [Portal 2 Beta has been released for Linux](http://steamcommunity.com/games/221410/announcements/detail/1585569369676516320). This means wine is no longer required to play Portal 2. It can now be directly installed from the Linux version of Steam.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have Ubuntu 13.04 installed and Portal 2 is a available for Linux, all you need to do is to download Steam for Ubuntu from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve.

Comment: Portal 2 is not yet available for Linux, only Portal 1 can be played natively on Linux. Please see http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/06/portal-leaves-beta-hits-linux for more information.